# My c assmbler program is throwing SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) and I have no idea why

Tags: c, assembly

I am trying to build a c assmbler but there is a line in the function "get_label that is throwing:
SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault).

Specifically the start of line 2 from the file below, the "LOOP:" is what does it, although the "MAIN:" in the line before doesn't. I know it is most likely a thing like memory leak some where in the program but I have no idea if it is or how to check it. I am new to this language.

how can I make this function work properly? help would be much appreciated and any other tips would be welcomed.

## File

MAIN: mov @r3 ,LENGTH
LOOP: jmp L1
mcro m1
...rest of file

## FUNCTION

```
char *get_label(char *token) {
    char *label;
    label = (char *) malloc(MAX_LABEL_LEN); //<-- THIS LINE

    if (label == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Memory allocation failed for label in line %d.\n", line_count);
    }
    char *label_ptr = label;
    PUT_WORD(label_ptr, token);


    if(is_label_decleration(label))
        {
        label[strlen(label) - 1] = '\0';
        }

    if (get_commend(label) != NOT_OPCODE)
        {/*checks if the label is a command name*/
        valid_file = NOT_VALID;
        printf("ERROR: the label %s with invalid name at line %d, can't use command keyword as label\n", label,
               line_count);
        return NULL;
        }
    if (!isalpha(*label))
        {
        valid_file = NOT_VALID;
        printf("ERROR: the label %s with invalid name at line %d, can't start label with non letter character\n",
               label, line_count);
        return NULL;
        }
    label_ptr = label;
    while (isalnum(*++label_ptr));
    if (*label_ptr != '\0')
        {
        valid_file = NOT_VALID;
        printf("ERROR: the label %s with invalid name at line %d, can't have label with non letter or digit character\n",
               label, line_count);
        return NULL;
        }

    return label;
}
```

here is the repository:
[(https://github.com/Coffee4Cup/assmbler)](https://github.com/Coffee4Cup/assmbler)

At start I tryed the strdup fucntion as it does what I want but that didn't work, then tryed to use the PUT_WORD macro function I built and the malloc as is writen now in the program.
I thought that if the malloc and strdup don't work then it is most likly a memory issue that I dont understand. since strdup returns allocated memory.

Comment: Why do you have `**label = ` doesn't `label = ` do what you want?

Comment: thank you for your fast comment. It is a typo, when writing the question I tried to make the problematic line bold. it is indeed a "label =" in the original file.

Comment: Right, it won't bold code. Where do you define `MAX_LABEL_LEN`?

Comment: it is in the header file, the length is longer then the length of "LOOP:":
#ifndef ASSMBLER_ASSMBLER_H
#define ASSMBLER_ASSMBLER_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lookup_table.h"
...
#define MAX_LABEL_LEN 31 <--here

Comment: You might wan to check that value, because if a simple malloc is failing, you're probably providing a bad value, or running out of memory. Can you reduce this down to a complete compilable example?

Comment: hope I got you right, I made this: void example(void){
    char *label;
    label =  malloc(sizeof(char) * 31);
    /*rest of code*/
} and made it run right before the get_label. error message is now: warning: Critical error detected c0000374
gdb: unknown target exception 0xc0000374 at 0x7ff95001c239

Thread 1 received signal ?, Unknown signal.
0x00007ff95001c239 in ntdll!RtlIsZeroMemory () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
[Thread 8172.0x4278 exited with code 3221226356]
[Thread 8172.0x30b8 exited with code 3221226356]
[Inferior 1 (process 8172) exited with code 030000001564]

Comment: I searched around for the meaning of this, maybe heap corruption? not sure what it means or how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems dangerous:

```
#define PUT_WORD(A,B) while((*(A)++ = *(B)++) != '\t' && *((A) - 1) != ',' && *((A) - 1) != ' '); \
*(A - 1) ='\0';
```

It doesn't check for a 0 terminator in the source string (B).

eg. you are using PUT_WORD once or twice inside get_command_parameters, but the last parameter might not be followed by any of '\t', ',', ' ' .

Comment: This was it! can't believe that I missed it. thank you, now I only have to fix the other 99 problems...